# Removing all reactions from a message

Tags: discord.js

I currently have my bot sending an embed then reacting to it.
I was wondering how I would go on removing all reactions from this message.
Code:

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
let prefix = '~';

client.on('message', async message => {
   if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'help'
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Help Cmd')
      .setDescription('example')

      let msg = await message.channel.send(embed);
      await msg.react('▶');
      await msg.react('◀');
      
      setTimeout(() => {
         //Removing all reactions from msg
      }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: [`msg.reactions.removeAll()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionManager?scrollTo=removeAll)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`msg.reactions.removeAll();`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionManager).